# Netbeans has "Print to HTML" - is there a way to add this feature to Eclipse?

Tags: html, eclipse, netbeans, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting

I want to print out some syntax-highlighted Ruby and Python code and Netbeans has a feature on the File menu for "Print To HTML". I'm wondering if there is a plugin or some add-on for Eclipse that enables a feature like this since it is my preferred IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install the [Java2Html](http://www.java2html.de/eclipse.html) plugin, however it does not directly send it to a printer. Only to a clipboard or to a file (html or .doc since it can apply those styles in RTF as well as CSS). You can then print the result.

The plugin is made for eclipse2.x.

I just tested it with eclipse 3.5Mx (latest eclipse)... and it does work!

[image]
<sub>(source: [java2html.de](http://www.java2html.de/eclipse_preferences.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Another Eclipse plugin which does export java source code to an html file with appropriate CSS styles is [**CS4Eclipse**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cs4eclipse/)

It is more recent (2008), but less sophisticated in its output format (no css files, only inline style), and a little less at ease with annotations.

However, it does support other sources than just java code (CSS, properties, XML, ... are valid sources to be exported to an HTML file)

Also tested with eclipse 3.5Mx.

[image]